# onDestroy() called when a in activity landscape mode android

Tags: android, android-activity

When an app activity is in landscape mode, and when a call comes in, the call will make the scene to portrait mode,

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_jum);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

}
```

after the call, the activity in the app that was in landscape mode gets destroy and created again.

```
D/StartJumActivity: onPause
D/StartJumActivity: onResume
D/StartJumActivity: onPause
D/StartJumActivity: onDestroy
D/StartJumActivity: on Create
```

The data in my activity gets removed and new activity is created.
Is there any way to retain those data in that activity in landscape mode after returning from the call?

Comment: Please take a look at the Android lifecycle, this is a basic "feature" of Android that can be fixed by using something like MVVM. Otherwise use savedInstanceState and take a look at Lifecycle tutorials

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try forcing the orientation of the `Activity` in the manifest:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

This may prevent the `Activity` from being destroyed and recreated.

Another alternative would be to tell Android that you will handle the orientation change yourself and not to recreate your `Activity` on an orientation change. To do that add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to the manifest declaration for your `Activity`. Now, when the screen orientation occurs, your `Activity` will not be destroyed and recreated. Instead, `onConfigurationChange()` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `onSaveInstanceState()`to save your own data and restore it using `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`. Check out this for more information [https://www.todaysoftmag.com/article/2663/when-do-screen-orientation-changes-matter#:~:text=In%20Android%2C%20the%20orientation%20changes,called%2C%20followed%20by%20onCreate()](https://www.todaysoftmag.com/article/2663/when-do-screen-orientation-changes-matter#:%7E:text=In%20Android%2C%20the%20orientation%20changes,called%2C%20followed%20by%20onCreate())).

Answer (score 0):

Add
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**